# Filewatcher bash that runs a curl

Tags: bash, shell

I have no experience in bash, and I must create one of the type filewatcher that when a file like "**FILE_RECEIVED.CSV**" arrives in a local directory "**C:/directory/**", it executes a curl (GET method ) containing the name of that received file.
Something like this:

curl http://localhos:3030/load/process-file?filename=**FILE_RECEIVED.CSV**&filePathFile=C:/directory/

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ];
then
    echo "especificar un directorio como argumento"
    echo "$0 <dir>"
    exit 1
fi

while true;
do
    for a in $(ls -1 $1/* 2>/dev/null);
    do
        curl "[http://localhost:3000/load/process-file?filenam=art_2021_inv.csv&filePathFile=C:/Users/mgarc/repo/"
    done
    sleep 2s
done

executar:
./filewatcher_curl.sh <directorio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inotifywait` to watch changes in a directory. First, if not installed you should install `inotifywait`. In ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

Then, wait for a `CREATE` event, and get the result with:

```
NEW_FILE_NAME=$(inotifywait -e CREATE ${DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH} | grep CREATE  | awk '{print $3}')
# what ever you want to do with ${NEW_FILE_NAME}
```

Note that this is just an example and it is not perfect, because for example if two files created simultaneously, you may miss one.